# Php contact form send from title

Tags: php, html, forms, contacts

I have a contact form on my website that is a simple php contact form. When someone uses the form and submits it, I do get the email but it always says the email is from name@gator4091@hostgator. I do use host gator as my hosting company but is there any way to change something in the php to make it come from something else like maybe contact(at)mywebsite ? Or is this something I can't change ?

Comment: Would really need to include more information. The source for the contact form would be a start.

Comment: There are a ton of ways to actually send mail.  How are we to know which you are using?

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: A quick google came up with this from hostgator support: http://support.hostgator.com/articles/specialized-help/technical/php-email-from-header Typically things from a specific host have been answered somewhere in support at that host. Especially one as large as hostgator. That should be your first place to look.

Comment: [`$headers = "From: ".$name." <".$email.">\r\nReply-To: ".$email."";`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided your PHP emailer script uses a standard [`mail()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php), you need to do a `"From: myemail@mydomain.com"` in the header.

Taken from the [**PHP manual**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) (notice line one of the `$headers` line):

```
<?php
$to      = 'nobody@example.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```